# How can I handle the from() of an ActiveMQ consumer Camel route for in-container testing?

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel, activemq-classic, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to use Arquillian to run JUnit tests of my Java Camel routes in WildFly 11.

The problem is, the route (which extends RouteBuilder) is starting to poll the MQ broker AS SOON as it's initialized (or warmed up?), which is, long before my test code has a chance to run and mock the from("activemq:queue:myqueue") of the route. Then of course it hangs there because it tries the (camel hardcoded) default 61616 port.

I also tried to extend the DefaultCamelContext but if I @Observe CdiCamelConfiguration and set autoConfigureRoutes(false) and although the wrong polling doesn't happen anymore (yay) also CDI doesn't happen anymore and all injected things are null (buuh) when later I load the route by hand in the test class.

```
@ApplicationScoped
class MyCamelContext extends DefaultCamelContext {
    @PostConstruct
    void manual() throws IOException {
        setAutoStartup(false); // cool but doesn't help as camel 
                 // dows the warmup anyway, so activemq will poll
    }

    static void configuration(@Observes
    final CdiCamelConfiguration configuration) {
        configuration.autoConfigureRoutes(false); // cool but breaks CDI
    }
}
```

There's nothing I can do in a test case or test suite, obviously (they are run even later). I could (re)define the route with a from("direct:blah") but I'd like to keep the route code as it is. Also defining the route to not autostart is not helping because activemq starts polling as soon as the RouteBuilder bean is created.

I thought of deploying with the shrinkwrap archive also a queue-jms.xml but I don't know what I could put there to save the situation. Or to overwrite the brokerURL somehow but I can't find any way how.

However, how can I init the route beans WITHOUT any of them trying to poll anything?

Versions: Camel 2.21.0 in WildFly 11 - actually JBoss EAP 7.1.5 with Fuse 7.2.

Comment: ...and the question is?

Comment: How can I handle the from() of an ActiveMQ consumer Camel route for in-container testing?

Comment: I have no idea about Arquillian. Is the techniques used in [this testcase](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-amqp/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/amqp/AMQPRouteTest.java) of any help to you?

Comment: Hmm it's a good example and I'll bookmark it thanks. However in my particular case it doesn't help, because the routes are started by the test container much before the testcases, so @BeforeClass comes much too late to be of any help...